# Can docker have multiple logging drivers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

is it possible to use multiple logging drivers for the same container - say fluentd and json?

Thank you.

Comment: This is an open feature request and is being tracked [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/17910)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of 18.03, Docker Engine Enterprise(EE) supports multiple log drivers, but it is not in the Community Edition(CE):

https://docs.docker.com/ee/engine/release-notes/#18031-ee-1-2018-06-27

Comment: It is to the release notes that shows that the multiple logging driver support was added:  
- Add support for multiple logging drivers for docker logs.

Comment: FYI this is not the same as multiple logging drivers. This feature only supports viewing logs locally via docker logs, while using one other logging driver.

Comment: Now docker-ce 20 supports dual logging

Answer (score 11):

Dual logging is available in docker CE since version `20.10.1`.

The feature was previously only available in Docker Enterprise since version `18.03.1-ee-1`.

The official documentation chapter "[Dual Logging](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/dual-logging/)" doesn't reflect this (as of 2021-01-04 ).

The feature has been open-sourced in pull request [#40543](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40543) and was merged into `master` on 2020-02-27.

The related GitHub issue [#17910](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/17910) in `moby/moby` was closed with the following comment:

> The upcoming Docker 20.10 release will come with the feature described above ("dual logging"), which uses the local logging driver as a ring-buffer, which makes docker logs work when using a logging driver that does not have "read" support (for example, logging drivers that send logs to a remote logging aggregator).

Comment: FYI this is not the same as using multiple logging drivers. This feature only supports viewing logs locally via docker logs, while using one other logging driver.

Infact that page states "You cannot specify more than one log driver."

And in direct response to this question, the "dual logging", would only support fluentd and simple, it would not be able to support fluentd and json.

Comment: Jeah you're \*somewhat\* correct - docker can use multiple logging drivers but with the internal dual logging feature you can only chosse a combination of  local driver plus any other driver. just use [logspout](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout) with the [logsput-fluentd](https://github.com/dsouzajude/logspout-fluentd) module for other cases. Thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can only specify a single logging driver/container.

To have separate sinks for your logs, you'd have to rely on something like fluentd to receive the logs (or read the json log files) and configure a pipeline to distribute them.

Answer (score 3):

No you can specify a single logging driver as stated in [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/dual-logging/) :

> You cannot specify more than one log driver.

The log-driver documentation indicates that too :

> To configure the Docker daemon to default to a specific logging
>   driver, set the value of log-driver to the name of the logging driver
>   in the daemon.json file...`

```
{
  "log-driver": "syslog"
}
```

You can see that `"log-driver"` expects a string  and not an array.

In fact, since Docker Engine Enterprise 18.03.1-ee-1, Docker has "just" enable a dual logging feature that allows to configure any logging driver log while being still the possibility to read them with `docker logs`.
For example before that feature, specifying that driver in the daemon.json :

```
{
  "log-driver": "syslog"
}
```

allowed to redirect the logs to a syslog server but that also made Docker to not publish any longer logs to the local logging driver.
Now that is not the case, the information is available in both destination.

> Starting with Docker Engine Enterprise 18.03.1-ee-1, you can use
>   docker logs to read container logs regardless of the configured
>   logging driver or plugin. This capability, sometimes referred to as
>   dual logging, allows you to use docker logs to read container logs
>   locally in a consistent format, regardless of the remote log driver
>   used, because the engine is configured to log information to the
>   “local” logging driver.